# Swift path separator

Tags: ios, swift, path, uikit, foundation

I know there is a symbol `os.pathsep` in python means to get the os path separator, also I found another [`pathSeparator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbrowser/1407688-pathseparator) do the same for macOS which comes from `AppKit`.

Question: is there any replacements which defined under the `Foundation.framework` or `UIKit.framework`? Swift is open-source, so I think there should be some definitions, right?

BTW, I'm looking for this for iOS with `UIKit` environment and using `/` constant string temporarily.

Comment: Instead of constructing file paths manually, you can use file URL APIs of `NSURL` and `FileManager`.

Comment: I just want a `String` separator defined in system framework, for performance issue and complexity, I don't wanna `NSURL` or other. @EugeneDudnyk

Comment: There is only one OS involved here, iOS, so you are fine with a hardcoded separator.

Comment: `pathSeparator` from `NSBrowser` has nothing to do with the file system. UIKit uses `/` and nothing but `/`. – Using URL and FileManager methods should still be the correct way to go. What kind of performance issues to you have?

Comment: For example: `URL(fileURLWithPath: ".").pathComponents?.first` could return the my expectation `/` but it needs a `URL` object anyway and not simple directly. @MartinR

Comment: Inspired by @JoakimDanielson 's tips, I used a simple wrapper method `pathSeparator` with returning `/` to make it meaningful.